# MS Word Conditional Formatting

Tags: microsoft-word

So I know the basics of MS Word but wish to add some conditional formatting for the attached example table so that the risk rating calculates itself when the likelihood and severity are completed.

I've never used conditional formatting before so need it explained in REALLY simple terms!

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Mel[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaPkM.jpg)

Comment: He/ she probably wants when he enters L/M/H in the third box, the color of that cell automatically changes to Green/ yellow/ Red respectively.

Comment: I am not aware if there is conditional formatting in MS Word, though it can be achieved by macros. Conditional formatting is there in MS Excel as a simple menu option. As your example has a table, the same can be achieved in MS Excel, then define conditional formatting for it in excel, save it and insert those Excel cells in MS Word with Menu - Insert - Object - Create New - MS Excel Worksheet.